# How can I animate an ImageView after I applied transformations on it?

Tags: android, animation, imageview, zooming

I am trying to implement the zoom and drag features for an image viewer. So far I created the custom ImageView and implemented the actual features for pinch zoom and drag using the transformation matrix of the view. Now I want to animate the transition from the last position to a legal one (the user can drag the image where he/she wants but when it is released it should bounce back). If I just make modifications on the transformation matrix it works but, as I said, I want animations.

My problem is that if the image is out of the screen and I animate the view back the image is cut and remains truncated even after the animation is finished. I should mention that the image is set using the setImageUri method.

Does anyone have any idea on this one?

Comment: ok as you say that cutting might be because of using setImageUri then check out by just setImageBitmap or try to invalidate the imageview so that it refreshes its view again.

Comment: From what I can see, when I apply transformations the content of the view changes and when I apply animations the view itself changes. This is why my image is being cut when I try to animate the entire view. I have no other idea but to create some thread in which I'll animate the view through transformations. Not the best solution though.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find a way to animate the view the way I want so I created my own animation in a separate thread using the transformation matrix.